# UITableView Delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I am trying to call `reloadData` on my `UITableView`. I am making my app without interface builder.

This code would works with Interface Builder, but does not seem to without.

When I compare my code to what I used to do in interface builder, I am missing the bit in code where I would drag the View Controller to the `UITableView`. I have the delegates and datasource set and working. Is there something I am missing in my code?

**EDIT:**
This is set up in my viewDidLoad
The _tableView has the property set and is Synthesized.

```
//Data is set into an NSArray then copied into an NSMutableArray
_nsarray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docPath error:NULL];

_nsmArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[_nsmArray addObjectsFromArray:_nsarray];

_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];


-(void)refreshTable {
    //_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Where and how have you allocated this tableview

Comment: Nothing seems wrong in that code. Which change are you expecting when you `reloadData`? How do you populate the table view?

Comment: I am populating it with an NSMutableArray, it is the array of the Document folder. I am testing it when I remove files from the folder, which is when I want it to update the TableView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How are you managing your table data? NSArray?**

You need to provide these details as what you have posted should work: setting the `dataSource` and `delegate` and calling `reloadData`. When you simply "`reloadData`" you need to ensure there were changes to the dataSource. If no changes were made to the dataSource *(i.e. add / remove an object from the array)*, then nothing is going to happen.

Comment: I have added more code to help - I am using an NSMutableArray

Comment: The code you added does not help. Are altering the `dataSource` in any way before you **`reloadData`**?

Comment: This is a copy of the comment above: I am populating it with an NSMutableArray, it is the array of the Document folder. I am testing it when I remove files from the folder, which is when I want it to update the TableView.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean - I have never needed specific code for that. i am not deleting it from the TableView. I delete the files when I view them, then when I return to the UITableView it has not updated.

Comment: You delete the files when you view them? That doesn't make any sense. Do you delete the from the app? How / when are you creating the array to begin with? Let's start there. I would go with `viewWilLAppear:` and re-iterate through the contents of the documents again in there. THEN you can call reloadData.

Comment: That works - I loaded the TableView from viewDidLoad into the viewWillAppear as well and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you set correctly the delegate and the data source? Like this:

```
    [tableView setDelegate:self];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
```

And then you have to call the method "reloadData" in the main thread, so you should call your method "refreshTable" like this:

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly saying you need only two things to be able to display data in the table view:

1) `self.tableView` must be pointing to the table view, so you can call `reloadData` when required.

2) table view's `dataSource` property must be assigned to your class, which must implement required methods from the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have added UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols in your **.h file.**

```
@interface YourClassName : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

and then set your tableview delegate and dataSource to self.

EX:

```
    [yourTableView setDelegate:self];
    [yourTableView setDataSource:self];
```